# How to prevent strange email to regiser my site

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a bit problem with account register on my site

Now, I just see one email account have been register with my site, It is so strange, that email is 1334395@rtrtr.com, and I don't know for sure how many similar mails are there.

I don't want this email can register with my account, Because I'm afraid with spam mail or Hackers.

How can I prevent from all of it?

Answer (score 8):

Don't.

It's a valid e-mail address.  You shouldn't be blocking it, nor preventing it.  Even if you try, you will not be preventing spammers (which is what you are really trying to accomplish).

To actually prevent fake registrations, there are many techniques, from CAPTCHA to simply requiring JavaScript for your signup form to work.  None of them are fool-proof... they all can be worked around, but they go a long ways towards helping.

Comment: @user1641601 make a simple captcha involving 2 random numbers adds up and require user to key in the correct answer. Therefore, you need not to download plugins like Re-CAPTCHA

Comment: Yes, my register page have captcha already, but I'm a little scared !

So I am no need to blocking it right?

Comment: You should care about your coding that are vunerable to SQL injection :D

Comment: Yes, I'm using codeigniter framework and I follow up with it's SQL

Thank you so much for consideration on me!

Answer (score 4):

You could always make registration a two part process.

1. Register with website using email address
2. Send email with verification link that activates the account

Depending on how your system is set up, you could then clear all users with unverified email addresses after a week (or whatever time range you desire.)

Comment: Yes, I was adapted with this step also, thank you for your telling me!

Comment: To me, this is the obvious solution and the only one you need.